# Passing parameters in rmarkdown to the text or headings

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there any way to pass parameters in an rmarkdown document outside of a code chunk? For example, I'd love to have the ability to have a parameter value be a heading.

Here is a short example `.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "param_test"
author: "test"
date: "September 14, 2017"
output: pdf_document
params:
  param_test: this_text
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## I want this heading to be the value of params$param_test

```{r cars}
params$param_test

print(params$param_test)
```
````

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to add `results='asis'` to the chunk then you can print out the header from within the code.

`cat("#", params$param_test, "\n")`

Another option would be to use the pander library and run

pandoc.header(params$param_test)

Comment: This EXACTLY what I wanted.